# Duplicates and removing records

Tags: duplicates, data-cleaning

I have a large dataset (df) with millions of rows, I want help finding an efficient way of doing the following

Dataset: df

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVsBa.png)

1. I want to pull out rows that have same patient ID and year of diagnosis (patient 3)- df_new
2. Notice, that despite having the same year of diagnosis, patient 3 has different age at diagnosis. I would like to use the year of birth to validate age at diagnosis and then keep that record in place (age=64 in this case)
3. Going back to the main dataset (df1), I want to keep one record per patient, so that only the row containing their earliest diagnosis remains.
   In the main dataset, for patients with a case like that described in Q2, I want to keep only the record with their correct age.
   Final dataset:
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZInB.png)

I tried using duplicate, match and other statements but I cannot find an efficient way of doing the above in one code chunk instead of having to create multiple datasets